# multiple EC2 Instances matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the following script to query a particular instance. There will be only one running instance with the given name. It is possible that another instance with the same name may exists but in different instance state.

How do I filter instance on instance's state so it only retrieves instance that is running state?

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["dev-us-west-2-myinstance"]
  } 
}
```

Currently I get the following error

> multiple EC2 Instances matched; use additional constraints to reduce
> matches to a single EC2 Instance

Answer (score 2):

The [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance), links to [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) for the `describe-instances` filter.

That documentation indicates you should do the following:

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["dev-us-west-2-myinstance"]
  } 

  filter {
    name   = "instance-state-name"
    values = ["running"]
  } 
}
```